# Как выбрать определенные записи и применить к столбцу функцию?

Tags: pandas

У меня есть некий датасет, например:

```
  Marked       City.      Marked
1   0          New York    1
2   1         California   0
```

Хочу выбрать записи из фрейма данных, где `Marked` равен 1, и применить некоторую функцию к строке `City`. Фрейм данных большой (более 1 миллиона записей), а функция для применения затратная по ресурсам, поэтому вариант использования условия в `apply` для всего фрейма данных не подходит, поскольку мне все равно нужно пройти 1 миллион записей. Выбор строк во фрейме данных где `Marked` 1 снижает кол-во до 300 т. Соответсвенно, применить функцию к ним будет эффективнее, чем ко всему фрейму.

```
mask = test.Marked == 1
test.loc[mask, 'City'] = test.loc[mask].apply(exctract_actual_place_of_residence, axis=1)
```

но получаю ошибку:

> 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: А вы уверены, что ошибка не в функции `exctract_actual_place_of_residence`?

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, вы правы, сделал простую функцию и код сработал, спасибо

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
test.loc[mask, 'City'] = test.loc[mask, 'City'].apply(exctract_actual_place_of_residence, axis=1)
```

Comment: Может ему не только поле `City` в функции нужно )  Хотя как в случае `axis=1` работает `apply` я не очень могу сообразить...

Comment: @CrazyElf, возможно, этого я знать не могу. Наверное было бы больше пользы если бы автор задал вопрос о том как оптимизировать функцию `exctract_actual_place_of_residence()`. Есть ненулевая вероятность, что эту функцию можно реализовать векторизированным способом